# creating a grid using table element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying you to create a grid from a table element and then let the user color it. I'm now stuck on creating the table, I added the loop that is going to append the row element and the cell element but for some reason, the table wouldn't be created. can someone please point me in the right direction?

my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my javascript is:

```
// Select color input
var color = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
// Select size input
var height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
var width = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;
// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
document.querySelector('#sizePicker').addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'submit') {  // ← verifies target is desired element

        makeGrid(height,width);
    }
});
//add addEventListener to color eatch cell
function makeGrid(height,width) {
const mainTable = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

for (let i = 0 ; i <= height ; i++){
  mainTable.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', document.createElement('tr'));
      for (let x = 0; x <= width ; x++){
        mainTable.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',document.createElement('td'));
      }
}


}
```

my css is :

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the submit form action when click on the button.

DOM manipulation is expensive. So you'd want to create the chunk of elements first before appending it to HTML page. Otherwise it will take a bad performance hit.

```js
// Select color input
var colorEl = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
// Select size input
var heightEl = document.getElementById("inputHeight");
var widthEl = document.getElementById("inputWidth");
// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
document.querySelector('#sizePicker').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  const height = heightEl.value;
  const width = widthEl.value;
  const color = colorEl.value;
  
  makeGrid(height, width);

});
//add addEventListener to color eatch cell
function makeGrid(height, width) {
  const mainElement = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');
  // Your code goes here!
  const tableElement = document.createElement('table');
  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {

    const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      trElement.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    }

    tableElement.appendChild(trElement);

  }
  mainElement.innerHTML = '';
  mainElement.appendChild(tableElement);


}
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <div id="pixelCanvas"></div>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the whole issue because of the default behavior, thank you sit

Comment: but why did you change the table element to div element ?

Comment: You also need to move color, height, width declarations inside `addEventListener` (after `event.preventDefault()`) so that the submit function can capture those values in the form

Comment: Another point is that @afbigdad you used `insertAdjacentHTML`, which takes a HTML text, not an element. 
Source: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML]

Comment: it worked just fine but why did the rows separated by white space?

Comment: you need you use CSS to style as you want. Look in to DOM reflow and perfomance. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow. You need to update the HTML one time not 1000 times (if someone select 100 rows).

Comment: @MonteCristo now just one final question, how to reset the form from the submit button?

Comment: what I mean is, still when I press the submit button it creat a new grid instead of resetting the colors of the grid itself.